# Touch a file - update it's modified time stamp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is there an efficient way to update the last modified property of a file on the iPad's filesystem i.e. the unix touch command?

I've had a look at NSFileManager but no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so I'm answering my question just after I've asked it :(

I've found the method [setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:) in the NSFileManager class and I can specify the modified timestamp there.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9):

To update the modification timestamp (which is, for example, shown in the output of `ls -l`) of `filePath` to now:

```
NSError* error;
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager setAttributes:@{NSFileModificationDate:[NSDate date]}
                   ofItemAtPath:filePath
                          error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't update modification date: %@", error);
}
```